# Make a message box function in console and pass arguments (text) to it

Tags: c++, console, message

The code bellow will wrap the `std::string message` in a self adjusting double lined box, like in the old school DOS era.

How can I pass to this function a custom text message like `Msg_Box(print this custom text);` ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void Msg_Box()
{
    // Box edges and corners (all double thick line)
    // T for top, B for bottom, L for left, R for right
    const char TB = '\xCD'; // 205
    const char LR = '\xBA'; // 186
    const char TL = '\xC9'; // 201
    const char TR = '\xBB'; // 187
    const char BL = '\xC8'; // 200
    const char BR = '\xBC'; // 188

    std::string message = "To be, or not to be...";
    std::string margin = "  ";
    std::string line(message.length() + 2 * margin.length(), TB);

    std::cout << TL << line << TR << std::endl;
    std::cout << LR << margin << message << margin << LR << std::endl;
    std::cout << BL << line << BR << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;
    
}

int main()

{
        Msg_Box(); 
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hehe you already did the hard work!
You can pass a message like this :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

// pass a std::string to Msg_Box
// do it by reference to avoid copying.
// and make it const because you will
// not be changing the content of the string
void Msg_Box(const std::string& message)
{
    // Box edges and corners (all double thick line)
    // T for top, B for bottom, L for left, R for right
    const char TB = '\xCD'; // 205
    const char LR = '\xBA'; // 186
    const char TL = '\xC9'; // 201
    const char TR = '\xBB'; // 187
    const char BL = '\xC8'; // 200
    const char BR = '\xBC'; // 188

    std::string margin = "  ";
    std::string line(message.length() + 2 * margin.length(), TB);

    std::cout << TL << line << TR << std::endl;
    std::cout << LR << margin << message << margin << LR << std::endl;
    std::cout << BL << line << BR << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::ostringstream os;
    os << "The answer is " << 42;
    Msg_Box(os.str());
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Pepijin Kramer Thanks. It works. Side effects: the self adjusting part is nice for only one line of text. /n will break the box.

Comment: Its funny, takes me back some 30 years. I think I wrote mini windowing systems using ascii-art (and colors/shadows) back then.  In a way it was easier back then, I could access bits of the screen directly in memory.

Comment: @Pepijin Kramer - another side effect is that can't be used with '<<some_variable' like 'cout', I'm sure this can be solved... do you have any quick solution?

Comment: Yup, as a quick fix use a ostringstream. I updated the example.